# Dynamically loading select boxes on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm dynamically populating several select boxes via ajax calls when my app first opens. When the page loads however, what I am noticing is my select boxes start out empty and then once populated they adjust their size accordingly. This is annoying and a bit of a UI distraction.

I do have the population methods within my document.ready method, but perhaps I am approaching this incorrectly?

```
$(document).ready( function(){

populateOptions(); // Populate our select box upon page load.

});

// Builds a select list and binds it to a class
function populateOptions(){

    var optionList = getOptions();
    var myList = "";

    // Loop over our returned result set and build our options
   for(i=0; optionList.length; i++){
       myList += "<option>"+optionList[i][1]+"</option>";
    }

    // Now take our myList and append it to our select
    $("#myOptionList").append(myList);
}

Options: <select id="myOptionList"></select>
```

Comment: "populating several select boxes via ajax calls" So there will be a delay while ajax request is replied, adding to document ready just makes sure request is sent as soon as DOM is ready.

Comment: How is that `=+` in your loop working for you ?

Answer (score 2):

you can set a width to the select by css

Comment: Thanks, I ended up going with that.

Answer (score 1):

Add a dummy option to show while Loading via AJAX:

```
<select id="myOptionList">
    <option>Loading...</option>
</select>
```

---

Clear "loading" option and add new list once available

```
$("#myOptionList").html('');
$("#myOptionList").append(myList);
```

---

to set width with css:

```
#myOptionList{
width:150px;
}
```

Comment: Meh, same thing happens - the select box will grow in width once the options come in. I suppose I could set a default width on the box to take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution would be to create your  child directly when your ajax function is called.

Before finishing your populateOptions() function, append the select to your .

I remember having this issue, it is possible to solve it but this is a very simple way to handle it.

Hope this help.